# How to randomly choose the outgoing address from an IPv6 pool using Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, proxy, ipv6

I'm trying to create and run a Node.JS proxy in a machine that has a pool of IPv6 addresses. I want the proxy to randomly choose one of these addresses for each request (making it difficult for the websites to track record of users' requests).

With **wget** I can achieve this by using the attribute *--bind-address* as following:

```
wget --bind-address OUTGOING_IP http://www.example.com/
```

Is there any way to achieve the same behavior using Node.JS?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're having trouble. At selecting a random IP or at knowing where to put that random IP? What kind of requests are you doing?

Comment: I'm having problem on both situations. I didn't find a way to force the outgoing IP, so I'm looking for it. Also, I'd like to know if there is a way to assing outgoing IPs randomly for each request.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make outbound HTTP requests from different IPs, have a look for "localAddress" option under "http.request":

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

If you want to start a TCP server to listen on a particular IP bound to your host, you would probably want to specify it when you create the server [i.e. server.listen(PORT, HOST)]:

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_class_net_server

-- ab1